# Can we find a torus on $K^3$ surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose in $P^3$ we have $K3$ surface defined by $x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4=0$ can we find a complex subvariety that is a torus?

Comment: Yes, of course: take any line $\ell$ on the surface (e.g. $y=ix$, $w=iz$), and a general plane through $\ell$. Its residual intersection with the surface is a smooth plane cubic, hence an elliptic curve.